# How to delete parts of HTML in a MYSQL database tables field that differs

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Is it actually possible to delete a complete `<table></table>` that is inside my product_description database field among other text?

My situiation is as follows?

Let's say I have 1000 products. Each product has a products_description. That field contains some text and a table. Now I want to delete the complete `<table></table>` for each product. But of course the data in the table is not identical for each product.

Can this be achieved automatical at all? Maybe with the help of PHP and regex or something?

Comment: Can you please provide proper explanation with some code you are using?

Comment: I am sorry, there is no code I am using. I was just wondering if that is possible at all. I know how to delete something from a database field. But I have no idea if it is possible to do what I tried to describe above.